# Fictitious use case to send confidential data

Tags: security, ipfs, network, smart-contract-wallets, chaindata

I am designing the network architecture of a Fictitious agency that needs to send confidential data.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to send images through the Ethereum network? I've read that, for example, NFT's aren't stored on chain but with an external protocol IPFS. If I can't use the chain how do I link the IPFS with the Ethereum network?
2. Want kind of conditions can get a smart contract? For example, can I create a contract that send a image each time a certain condition is met in the image? Or is the smart contract limited to information on chain?

Any technical, network details (no implementation) would be welcome.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A file uploaded on the IPFS network is identified by an ID which depends only on the content of the file itself i.e. the CID, substantially an hash. Generally contracts have in their storage only this hash, e.g. NFTs are contracts (usually ERC721) on the Ethereum network that have in their storage this kind of hash. None prohibits using different protocols than IPFS but it would be inappropriate to use a centralized one.
2. Saving information on the blockchain is expensive and you should design your system to store as little information as possible on the contracts. I don't think to completely understand your question but you could make a contract that, when called by an authorized address, transfer an NFT.
   However this call must be triggered externally, every transaction on the Ethereum network must be submitted by someone (or by another contract, that is submitted by someone in its turn) so you can't have a "running contract" that check when a condition is verified, anyway your functionality can check this condition when called and revert the transaction if the condition is not satisfied.